# Unable to get page via HTTPS with LWP::Simple in Perl

Tags: perl, https, lwp

I try to download a page from an HTTPS URL with Perl:

```
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'https://www.ferc.gov/xml/whats-new.xml';
my $content = get $url or die "Unable to get $url\n";
print $content;
```

There seems to be a problem. Just can't figure out the error. I can't get the page. Is the get request improperly coded?  Do I need to use a user agent?

Comment: How would we know? Was there an error message? Can you get to other pages? Is perl installed on your system?

Comment: Yes I have perl installed.  Error message prints out according to the code.  Yes I can get to other pages. I just tested it by replacing the url with http instead of https using http://google.com and it worked.  So is the problem with the HTTPS?

Comment: If you're on an old system, old versions, it used to be so that you need to install the Net::SSL or Net::SSLeay modules separately to use https with LWP::Simple. Try `sudo cpan NET::SSL` or `sudo cpan NET::SSLeay` or something.

Comment: Works for me. You could try using `getprint($url);` which should print status code and error message if unsuccessful. As a side note, add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of your program.

Comment: What is "*Error message prints out according to the code.*" supposed to mean? Do you get an error or not? If yes, what's the error message?

Comment: @KjetilS. Do not use `sudo cpan`. Among other issues, it can overwrite or remove system packages.

Comment: @melpomene. Maybe `sudo cpanm` then?

Comment: @KjetilS. No, that gives you the same results.

Answer (score 3):

[LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https) is needed to make HTTPS requests with LWP. It needs to be installed separately from the rest of LWP. It looks like you installed LWP, but not LWP::Protocol::https, so simply install it now.